# Last stage before bottling. Film appeared around top edge on glass and a few bubbles on surface

Tags: wine, contamination

My batch of wine has been stabilized, degassed, and clarified. It is in the last stage before bottling and a film has appeared on the top at the edge on the glass. Also, there are a few bubbles on the surface of the wine. It smells fine and the filmy deposit looks like a yeast overgrowth rather than bacteria. Is my wine ruined or should I bottle as usual?

Comment: Always good to add a photo, with a question like this

Answer (score 1):

A photo really would be best to judge your issue!

If you've observed regular safe procedures then it is very likely what has happened is that you've got a harmless yeast contamination, in which case you can remove the film and bottle.

Without further information I'd simply taste it and if it taste okay then it is likely just fine. Most really bad things also affect the flavor so in this case it is probably your best bet.